# Accessing Rails instance variable in AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest, angularjs

I am trying to set a $scope.list variable in angular to be equal to a `@users` variable in my rails controller under the index method...any help?

```
ex: $scope.list = Users.query();


User_profile.rb (controller)

def index

@users = User.all 

end
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you already have the `$scope.list` populated and want to set `@Users`, or the other way around?

Comment: @Malkus users returns a rails query and I want to be able to set the $scope.list variable to the result of the query. However I want to do so without doing $scope.list = <%=raw users.to_json %>. But im not sure on how to do so with a $resource or with some other angular method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to other problems people have in regards to using JQuery `$.ajax` calls with AngularJS

If you take a look at [this overview of Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) you will see Angular compiles everything into its own execution context.  You need to bring your Rails call to angular in order for the data to appear in the `$scope`

**The two options to resolve this are:**

1. Switch to the AngularJS `$http` service. *This would be my preference: everything will already be in Angular and you could remove your dependendy on an additional library*.
2. Wrap your call in the `$scope.$apply` method to trigger a `$digest` loop when the Rails call is finished

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help! Is there anyway I could get a code sample to look at to help me get a better idea of what to do?

Comment: Take a look at the angular [API Reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/) It is a nice resource and has a lot of working examples.

Comment: i am still struggling...maybe a quick example?

Comment: Which solution where you going to go with?

Comment: Solution #1...i really appreciate all the help

Comment: Did you see the working example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http)?  It can even be exported to plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: yes but how do i map a specific action in a rails controller to the http request in angular

Comment: You would go directly to the URL you are fetching data from instead of feeding through your Rails controller.  `$http` will do the get

Comment: back to the future in 2019 - any solution for the same problem ? still AngularJS, but not with $http, any working code ?