# How to access rails instance variable from within angularJS controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've a rails application which is connected to angularJS client. (the connection is via someview.html.erb files (what's called embedded ruby).
I have a rails controller and inside it:

```
@books = Book.find(1)
```

I would like to access this @books variable inside my angularJS controller: for example:

```
@scope.list_of_books = @books
```

What are my options ?

note: this post: [Accessing Rails instance variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020961/accessing-rails-instance-variable-in-angularjs)
did not help me. (I also could not realize what's the connection to $http whatsover or what is $scope.$apply

Comment: The Q/A you link to *is* the answer. Rails instance variables are *only* available during the *initial render*, e.g., whatever ERb you're using to render the Angular app. This is not, however, how most Angular apps are written, instead they (almost always) use API calls to retrieve their data.

Comment: Dave - thanks first. I could not translate that post suggested answer to a code. if my rails instance variables only available during the initial render, the angular controller has not way to access them ? I could not understand the solution to the problem

Comment: https://www.codewithjason.com/getting-started-with-angular-and-rails/, https://medium.com/@tommybernaciak/angular-on-rails-how-to-start-37e3851ffb60, etc. I think working through a simple tutorial first would be the easiest approach.

Comment: Dave, both articles refers to angular 2 wheres my problem refer to angularJS. Also, they do not suggest any solution to my problem or any idea that could lead me to a working solution.

Comment: The philosophy is the same regardless of the version. The first article is Angular 4, btw, and the second is likely the same. The both address accessing data from a Rails app using normal Angular processes ($http or whatever the current mechanism is). Your best bet is *still* a tutorial: Angular is *not* the same as old-style server-renders-everything; accessing an API is the standard mechanism for client-side apps. I don't know what else I can tell you. It's significantly easier (and cleaner) to do things the Angular Way.

Comment: Dave I absolutely agree. in my freelance projects I do ajax calls with a client project getting data through the sever api. However, this is about work, this project is not mine. it is an old project actually. (5 years old). and tha't the problem I try to solve. thankx by the way anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't matter-the same data can be returned as json with little or no effort. It's not clear what the issue is--if they're already doing it without http calls then mirror what's already there and working. If they're not then you can use whatever mechanism the version of angular they're using provides.

Comment: the first thing I did was trying to do it their buggy hacky way and failed  The way they did it is via something like: a service which runs inside a script tag inside a rails 'partial' and has methods that are responsible for the connection to the model in a peculiar way. Something like: modelService.getUsers = function() { return <%= listOfUsers %> } and listOfUsers is an instance variable initialized inside the rails controller: listOfUsers = User.find(...), And then injecting this service to the angular controller being able to go: @scope.users = modelService getUsers()

Answer (score 0):

the above article solved my problem:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/
with some interesting, yet hacky solutions to accessing rails instance variables inside angularJS app.
one solution (hacky):

```
<div ng-controller="itemsControllerNgInit" 
     ng-init="init('<%= @item.name %>', <%= @item.cost %>, <%= @item.id %>)">
  <h2> {{item.name}} ({{item.id}}) costs {{item.cost | currency}}  {{test}} </h2>
</div>
```

and the controller:

```
function itemsControllerHiddenDiv ($scope) {
    var div = document.getElementById('div-item-data');

    $scope.item = {name: div.getAttribute("data-item-name"),
                   cost: div.getAttribute("data-item-cost"),
                   id:   div.getAttribute("data-item-id")
    };
}
```